# How to pass Event as a parameter in JQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I am learning JQuery and I have written a small function where I am attaching a function with a button's click event.

this is the head element of the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(pageLoaded); 

    function pageLoaded() 
    {
        $("#Button1").bind("click", 
                            { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }, 
                            function buttonClick(event) 
                            {
                               $("#displayArea").text(event.data.key1);
                            }
                            );
    }                    

</script>
```

This is the body of the HTML

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />

<div id = "displayArea" style="border:2px solid black; width:300px; height:200px">
```

This code works fine. But when I try to write the buttonClick function outside the anonymus method, it does not work anymore.

I tried to call it this way:

```
$("#Button1").bind("click", 
                   { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }, 
                   buttonClick(event));

function buttonClick(var event) 
{
      $("#displayArea").text(event.data.key1);
}
```

This is not working. Am I doing some mistake while passing the Event as parameter? what is the correct way to do it without using anonymous methods?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pass a `function reference` as the click handler, but what you are doing here

```
$("#Button1").bind("click", 
                   { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }, 
                   buttonClick(event));
```

is calling `buttonClick(event)` immediately and which `return undefined` and sets that as the `click handler`. You have to pass a function reference like `buttonClick` and you will get event param automatically (jQuery will send that when calling the handler).

**Full Code:**

```
$(function(){
   $("#Button1").bind("click", 
                   { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }, 
                   buttonClick);

   function buttonClick(event) 
    {
      $("#displayArea").text(event.data.key1);
    } ​
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/cjc9r/

---

**Update (Based On @Tadeck's comment):**

Your code will work fine if you use `function expression` like this

```
var buttonClick = function(event){
    $("#displayArea").text(event.data.key1);
};
```

And you have to place this above its `first use`. In this case before

```
$("#Button1").bind("click", ...
```

Because `function expressions` are not `hoisted` at the top of current scope like `function declaration`. So you can use them `only after` the `expression` has been `interpreted` by `JS interpreter`.

Comment: +1 for being the first person to actually explain what they were doing wrong, rather than just posting code.

Comment: +1. It is worth mentioning, that if you define function the way it happens in this answer, everything will work. But if you define function like that: `var buttonClick = function(event){ ... }`, the definition would need to be placed before the "function reference" is being used (in this case: before `$("#Button1").bind(...)` is invoked).

Comment: @Tadeck, Thanks Sir, may I add that to my answer?

Comment: Thank you Joy, It works fine. earlier I was thinking that since I was calling the function, I need to match the function signature from my calling code.

Comment: @Tadeck, Sir, updated answer, check and feel free to edit, if you find anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your solution you will have to change

`var` is only used to define a variable not a parameter of a function

```
function buttonClick(event)
{
    $("#displayArea").text(event.data.key1);
}
```

The other thing is the way you are assigning the event handler.
You're assigning the return value of `buttonClick(event)` which will be `undefined`. Just pass it the function itself. The `event` object will be passed automatically by jQuery

```
$("#Button1").bind("click", 
                   { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" }, 
                   buttonClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as following:

```
$('input[name="pin-code"], input[name="work-pin"]').on({
        keypress: function(e) {
            numbersOnly(e);   //function
        }
    });


function numbersOnly(e) {    //function
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
       return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I passed the entire click event:

```
$('#body').click({event}, onClickMethod);

function onClickMethod(evt){
    console.log("Click evt:", evt);
}
```